# Part of my script keeps appearing in the browser and it doesn't work properly, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, xhtml

I'm currently working my way through a beginners php book and am trying to do an exercise that wants me to make a number guessing game.  After failed attempts on my own I looked to the appendix for the answer.  I've typed this code out multiple times and I believe is character for character what the answer key has and yet part of the script keeps appearing in the browser when I run the script.   What am I missing?
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    if ( isset($_POST["submitButton"] ) and isset( $_POST["guess"] ) ) {
        processForm();
    } else {
        displayForm( rand( 1, 100 ) );
    }

    function processForm() {
        $randNum = (int)$_POST["randNum"];
        $guessLeft = (int)$_POST["guessLeft"];
        $guess = (int)$_POST["guess"];

        if ( $guess == $randNum ) {
            displaySuccess( $randNum );
        } elseif ( $guess == 0 ) {
            displayFail( $randNum );
        } elseif ( $guess < $randNum ) {
            displayForm( $randNum, $guessLeft, "Too low, try again.");
        } else ( $guess > $randNum ) {
            displayForm( $randNum, $guessLeft, "Too high, try again.");
        }
    }

    function displayForm( $randNum, $guessLeft=5, $message="") {
    ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="randNum" value="<?php echo $randNum?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="guessLeft" value="<?php echo $guessLeft?>" />

                <?php if ( $message ) echo "<p>$message</p>" ?>
                <p>Guess my number.  You have <?php echo $guessLeft?> <?php echo ( $guessLeft == 1 ) ? "try" : "tries"?> left to guess correctly.</p>
                <p>What's your guess? <input type="text" name="guess" value="" style="float: none; width: 3em;" />
                                        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Guess" style="float: none;" /></p>
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
        }

        function displaySuccess( $randNum ) {
        ?>
            <p>You guess it! <?php echo $randNum?> is correct!</p>

            <form action="" method="post">
                <p><input type="submit" name="tryAgain" value="Try Again" style="float: none;" /></p>
            </form>

            <?php
            }

        function displayFail( $randNum ) {
        ?>
            <p>You ran out of guesses! My number was <?php echo $randNum?></P>

            <form action="" method="post">
                <p><input type="submit" name="tryAgain" value="Try Again" style="float: none;" /></p>
            </form>

            <?php
            }
            ?>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are several errors. First, you can't use a function before you declare it, and second, your forms do not have actions.

Comment: Which 'part' specifically? And like @casper said, there are several issues in the code.

Comment: I thought using the function before it was declared was odd, but like I said this is straight from the answer key in the appendix of Beginning PHP 5.3 by Wrox.  The part that shows up in the browser is from the second else if statement after the operation $randNum ) { displayForm( $randNum, $guessLeft, "Too high, try again."); } } function displayForm( $randNum, $guessLeft=5, $message="") { ?>
$message
" ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are running the script with out a webserver. I have tried it on my own and it seems to work except for some minor error that can be corrected. if you don't have a web server get one from [here](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). and install it. PHP won't run with out an interpreter and for it to work on a web browser you need a webserver.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php

if ( isset($_POST["submitButton"] ) and isset( $_POST["guess"] ) ) {
    processForm();
} else {
    displayForm( rand( 1, 100 ) );
}

function processForm() {
    $randNum = (int)$_POST["randNum"];
    $guessLeft = (int)$_POST["guessLeft"];
    $guess = (int)$_POST["guess"];

    if ( $guess == $randNum ){
        displaySuccess( $randNum );
    } elseif ( $guess == 0 ){
        displayFail( $randNum );
    } elseif ( $guess < $randNum ){
        displayForm( $randNum, $guessLeft, "Too low, try again.");
    } 
    elseif( $guess > $randNum ){
        displayForm( $randNum, $guessLeft, "Too high, try again.");
    }
}

function displayForm( $randNum, $guessLeft=5, $message="") {
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="randNum" value="<?php echo $randNum?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="guessLeft" value="<?php echo $guessLeft?>" />

            <?php if ( $message ) echo "<p>$message</p>" ?>
            <p>Guess my number.  You have <?php echo $guessLeft?> <?php echo ( $guessLeft == 1 ) ? "try" : "tries"?> left to guess correctly.</p>
            <p>What's your guess? <input type="text" name="guess" value="" style="float: none; width: 3em;" />
                                    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Guess" style="float: none;" /></p>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php
    }

    function displaySuccess( $randNum ) {
    ?>
        <p>You guess it! <?php echo $randNum?> is correct!</p>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <p><input type="submit" name="tryAgain" value="Try Again" style="float: none;" /></p>
        </form>

        <?php
        }

    function displayFail( $randNum ) {
    ?>
        <p>You ran out of guesses! My number was <?php echo $randNum?></P>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <p><input type="submit" name="tryAgain" value="Try Again" style="float: none;" /></p>
        </form>

        <?php
        }
        ?>



</body>
```

here is the one i run...

Comment: I'm running WAMP web server, maybe there's an error with it?  I've tried restarting services as well as stopping and starting.  I'm noticing an issue with other scripts I'm working on trying to use $_POST or $_GET and getting no results. A lot of what I'm finding online suggests it might be my server.. How would I resolve this? reinstall?

Comment: Wow, im an idiot!  I've been trying to run my php scripts from notepadd++ using the shortcut to run in browser rather than typing localhost/filename.php in the browser!  Omg I've been killing myself redoing the script...ugh.  Oh well!  I'm still running into an error with an "unexpected '{' " after the else statement..is that the minor error you were referring to?  How do I resolve this, I'm pretty sure I have the correct amount of brackets..

Comment: That's because the line with this code } else ( $guess > $randNum ) {
            displayForm( $randNum, $guessLeft, "Too high, try again.");
        } has an error. the "else" should be an "else if"

Comment: Thank you for the clarity!  I find it odd that there are so many small errors like this in my book.  I don't know enough about the php syntax to have even second guessed that being else vs elseif.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you've already accepted an answer, but I went ahead and coded you an example based off of your script. I figure if anything, it will help you in the future. There were many syntactical mistakes throughout your script. If you coded verbatim from your book, I would get rid of the book and look for better sources.

I took the liberty to modify a few things. If you have any questions, feel free to contact me.

This is a working copy of your game with a lot of changes throughout the script.

It works. Just save the code as guessing.php and run it in your browser.

```
<?php
// Set inital variables //
// Guesses for form //
$guessLeft = 5;
// Output message //
$message = '';
// Whether to show the form or not //
$showForm = true;
// Help message to help user decide where to go,
// Up or down, and how many guesses //
$helpMessage = '';

// Displays a fail message //
function displayFail($randNum) {
    $message = "You ran out of Guesses! My number was {$randNum}.";
    return $message;
}

// Displays a success message //
function displaySuccess($randNum) {
    $message = "You guessed it! {$randNum} is correct!";
    return $message;
}

// Displays a help message //
function helpMessage($help, $guessLeft) {
    // Check plural //
    $plu = ($guessLeft > 1) ? "tries" : "try";
    // Format Output message //
    $message = '<p>';
    $message .= $help;
    $message .= " You have {$guessLeft} {$plu} left to guess correctly";
    $message .= '</p>';

    return $message;
}

// Check that submit button has been set //
if (isset($_POST["submitButton"]) and isset($_POST["guess"])) {
    // Collect $_POST information //
    $randNum = (int) $_POST["randNum"];
    $guessLeft = (int) $_POST["guessLeft"];
    $guess = (int) $_POST["guess"];

    // Check user guess //
    if ($guess < $randNum) {
        // Number too low //
        // Decrease guesses left //
        $guessLeft -=1;
        $helpMessage = helpMessage('Too low, try again.', $guessLeft);
    } elseif ($guess > $randNum) {
        // Number too high //
        // Decrease guesses left //
        $guessLeft -=1;
        $helpMessage = helpMessage('Too high, try again.', $guessLeft);
    } else {
        // Number correct, hide form show message //
        $showForm = false;
        $message = displaySuccess($randNum);
    }

    // If there are no more guesses left //
    // Hide page and display fail message //
    if ($guessLeft == 0) {
        $showForm = false;
        $helpMessage = '';
        $message = displayFail($randNum);
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Guessing Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
    </head>
    <body>            

        <?php
        // Show help message if it is set //
        // Else display nothing //
        if (strlen($helpMessage)) {
            echo $helpMessage;
        }
        ?>

        <?php if ($showForm) { ?>
            <form action="guessing.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="randNum" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['randNum'])) ? $_POST['randNum'] : rand(1, 100); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="guessLeft" value="<?php echo $guessLeft; ?>" />
                <label for="guess">What is your guess?</label>
                <input type="text" name="guess" id="guess" value="" /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Guess" />
            </form>
            <?php
        } else {
            // Output Message //
            echo $message;
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @casper!  This is the fourth book that my school has me using from Wrox publishing, and up until now there hasn't been any reason to doubt one of the books information.  I really appreciate you taking the time to redo the script and provide thorough comments.  This will definitely aide me in my quest to understand php!